# The comparison of manifold learning example of scikit learn is not working with my dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, manifold

I changed the X and color variables of the exaple below with my dataset that has the exact shape as the [original version](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-compare-methods-py).

I get the error below:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_lu.py:71: RuntimeWarning: Diagonal number 1 is exactly zero. Singular matrix.
  RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 160, in null_space
    v0=v0)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 1605, in eigsh
    params.iterate()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 571, in iterate
    raise ArpackError(self.info, infodict=self.iterate_infodict)
scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackError: ARPACK error 3: No shifts could be applied during a cycle of the Implicitly restarted Arnoldi iteration. One possibility is to increase the size of NCV relative to NEV.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ylb17168/PycharmProjects/csd_test/test4.py", line 46, in <module>
    method=method).fit_transform(X)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 666, in fit_transform
    self._fit_transform(X)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 637, in _fit_transform
    random_state=random_state, reg=self.reg, n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 505, in locally_linear_embedding
    tol=tol, max_iter=max_iter, random_state=random_state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 168, in null_space
    % msg)
ValueError: Error in determining null-space with ARPACK. Error message: 'ARPACK error 3: No shifts could be applied during a cycle of the Implicitly restarted Arnoldi iteration. One possibility is to increase the size of NCV relative to NEV. '. Note that method='arpack' can fail when the weight matrix is singular or otherwise ill-behaved.  method='dense' is recommended. See online documentation for more information.
```

Could you please help me to spot the issue?
Thanks,
Zied